# How to intercept HTML5 input validation with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, required-field

```
<form ... onsubmit="return false">
   <input type="text" name="location" ...>
   <input type="url" ... required>
   ...
</form>
```

Now, if I enter a location and hit ENTER, the browser tells me that an URL is required which is not an expected or desired outcome. The ENTER should just be ignored.

---

### Question

How can I **prevent** the browser from checking the required field **after hitting ENTER** in the "location" input field and only let the browser check the "url" field when submitting the form with JavaScript using `form.submit()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the default behavior of enter button for your form elements.

Lets have an example:

HTML5 form as

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" required/>
  <input type="text" name="test2" id="test2" required/>
  <input type="submit" value="Test"/>
</form>
```

Then apply below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(form).find('input').on('keydown', function(e){
     if(e.which == 13) // KEY.ENTER = 13
       e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Based on above scenario, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/hY93D/40/).

Comment: I actually did this now but reduced the scope to the input fields in the form.

Comment: Simon, do I change my answer accordingly?

Comment: Simon, are you fine with the answer? Then it should be ready for the acceptance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [novalidate](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-novalidate) attribute in your form element:

```
<form method="post" action="..." novalidate>...</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I want to validate, but not on ENTER

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did now and what worked (using jQuery, where $form represents the ):

```
$form.find('input').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.which == KEY.ENTER) // KEY.ENTER = 13
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Use `which` instead of `keyCode` in order to always work properly, since it is a jQuery standardization: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: Simon, it will works fine for all the inputs. Have a look at my fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/hY93D/40/ for the same

Answer (score -2):

There is a specific method for handle a "submit".
Here's [here](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)!